# How to get manufacturer name from manufacturer id in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have a manufacturer id and I want to get manufacturer name. How can I get that?

How to get manufacturer name from manufacturer id?

```
  $brandid=$_REQUEST['brand-id'];  
  $collection =     Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
  $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Comment: is Manufacture an attribute ? and is it have dropdown type values?

Comment: Yes. Manufacturer is an attribute. And it has dropdown type of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the code

```
 $brandid=$_REQUEST['brand-id'];
$attribute_code= //manufaute attribute code
Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("catalog_product", $attribute_code); 
$options = $attribute_details->getSource()->getAllOptions(false); 
foreach($options as $option){
 // print_r($option) and find all the elements 
echo $option["value"]; echo $option["label"]; 
if($brandid==$option["value"]):
echo $option["label"]; 
endif;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is being retrieved from an attribute set up as a dropdown, and your attribute is `brand-id` you would use something like:

```
$collection->getAttributeText('brand-id')
```

to retrieve the attribute text associated with the dropdown id otherwise normally returned when you query for the attribute value.